# Allow me to transpose rows into columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table data as shown below.

```
+---------+----------+-------+--+
|  Name   | Semester | Score |  |
+---------+----------+-------+--+
| John    | Sem 1    |    80 |  |
| Michael | Sem 1    |    90 |  |
| Dennis  | Sem 1    |    65 |  |
| Peter   | Sem 1    |    70 |  |
| John    | Sem 2    |    65 |  |
| Michael | Sem 2    |    85 |  |
| Peter   | Sem 2    |    95 |  |
| George  | Sem 2    |    85 |  |
| Michael | Sem 3    |    80 |  |
| Peter   | Sem 3    |    70 |  |
| George  | Sem 3    |    75 |  |
| Dennis  | Sem 3    |    70 |  |
+---------+----------+-------+--+
```

I want to execute a query and get the following resultset.

```
Name    Sem 1   Sem 2   Sem 3   Avg Total
John    80      55              67.5
Michael 90      85      80      85
Dennis  65              70      67.5
Peter   70      95      70      78.33
George          85      75      80
```

Help me to build the query.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is likely better to do in the application since it is a matter of presentation, but you can do something like:

```
select Name
     , max(Sem1) as Sem1
     , max(Sem2) as Sem2
     , max(Sem3) as Sem3
     , avg(score)
from (
    select Name
         , case Semester when 'Sem 1' then score end as Sem1
         , case Semester when 'Sem 2' then score end as Sem2
         , case Semester when 'Sem 3' then score end as Sem3
         , score
    from data
) as T
group by Name
```

As pointed out by bluefeet, this can be simplified to:

```
select Name
     , max(case semester when 'Sem 1' then score end) as Sem1
     , max(case semester when 'Sem 2' then score end) as Sem2
     , max(case semester when 'Sem 3' then score end) as Sem3
     , avg(score)
from data
group by Name
```

Comment: What's the point of the subquery?  This could be done without all that extra code.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'll edit my answer

Comment: Thanks Lennart & bluefeet.....The solution worked perfect!!